# can I use 32-bit mongodb-client to connect to 64-bit mongodb-server?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

when I'm using 32-bit mongodb ,I want to upgrade to 64-bit ,but some PC can't support 64-bit OS,so I want to know whether I can use 32-bit mongodb-client to connect to 64-bit mongodb-server?

Answer (score 2):

The architecture of the client doesn't matter when connecting to the server. They speak over sockets. For the most part, the server doesn't even know or care what the client is.

Comment: Thanks,so you means just when our all PCs are 64-bit,we can use 64-bit mongodb?

Comment: @Wahaha: i dont understand what your asking, sorry. You can install whatever version of mongodb server suits your computers architecture. 32bit or 64bit. The clients connecting to it do not have to match the server.